# How can I use a self made tensorflow CNN model in a gradio app?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradio

I got a self made Tensorflow CNN dat I trained for handwritten digit recognition. The code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import mnist

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

model_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model_2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model_2.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=15)

# Evaluate the model
model_2.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)

# Save model 2
model_2.save("mnist_model.h5")
```

And I would like to use it in a gradio app just in local hosting.

I tried creating a simple gradio interface to do my prediction.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import gradio as gr

# Load the model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("mnist_model.h5")

app = gr.Interface(model, inputs=gr.Image(shape=(28, 28, 1)), outputs=gr.outputs.Label(num_top_classes=1))
app.launch()
```

When I input my image and I press the predict button i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gradio\routes.py", line 488, in run_predict
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1428, in process_api        
    inputs = self.preprocess_data(fn_index, inputs, state)
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1245, in preprocess_data    
    processed_input.append(block.preprocess(inputs[i]))
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gradio\components\image.py", line 279, in preprocess
    im = processing_utils.resize_and_crop(im, self.shape)
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gradio\processing_utils.py", line 135, in resize_and_crop
    return ImageOps.fit(img, resize, centering=center)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageOps.py", line 495, in fit
    return image.resize(size, method, box=crop)
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2082, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
TypeError: argument 1 must be sequence of length 2, not 3
```

I even tried modifying the shape to (28, 28) but then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gradio\routes.py", line 488, in run_predict
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1431, in process_api
    result = await self.call_function(
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1109, in call_function
    prediction = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gradio\utils.py", line 706, in wrapper
    response = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\matof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 295, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), found shape=(28, 28, 3)
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: the last line of the code in the question should be `model_2.save("mnist_model.h5")`...  was this a typo ?

Comment: Yes I took a line from another model I had instead of the one I actually use. I'll modify it. But the model I use is indeed model_2. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and try's I found the solution to my problem. Simply grayscaling was not enough. Turns out I had more steps to do. I will post the solution here since it still might be useful to those that want to try this.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import gradio as gr

# Load the model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("mnist_model_1.h5")

def predict_number(image):
"""Predicts the number from the image."""
# Convert the image to grayscale.
image_gray = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)

# Convert the image to a tensor.
image_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_gray)

# Resize the image to 28x28.
image_tensor = tf.image.resize(image_tensor, (28, 28))

# Cast the data to float32.
image_tensor = tf.cast(image_tensor, tf.float32)

# Add a batch dimension.
image_tensor = tf.expand_dims(image_tensor, 0)

# Normalize the data.
image_tensor = image_tensor / 255.0

# Get the prediction.
prediction = model.predict(image_tensor)

# Convert the prediction to a string label.
prediction_label = str(prediction.argmax())

  # Return the prediction label.
  return prediction_label


app = gr.Interface(predict_number, 
                 inputs=gr.Image(shape=(28, 28)), 
                 outputs=gr.Label(num_classes=10),
                 examples=[
                    '1_1.png', '1_2.png', '2_1.png', '2_2.png', '3_1.png',
                    '3_2.png', '4_1.png', '4_2.png', '5_1.png', '5_2.png',
                    '6_1.png', '6_2.png', '7_1.png', '7_2.png', '8_1.png',
                    '8_2.png', '9_1.png', '9_2.png', '0_1.png', '0_2.png']
                 )
app.launch()
```

Meanwhile there are some additions since I worked further on it for my use case the answer here should still be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

First of all. You're saving model, not model_2 here:

```
# Save model 2
model.save("mnist_model.h5")
```

When you run the code it should give you an error.

Second, I would assume that the reason for an error is that the image you're giving the model is a usual png image which have 3 channels (R/G/B), but you're training the model with 1 channel (see input_shape(28, 28, **1**)

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
```

You need to convert your test image to grayscale image(which has 1 channel not 3) and it should work fine

Comment: For the model, it was just another line I showed, instead of the one I used by mistake. It was notified by someone and I changed it. But thank you.

How can I implement grayscale for the image in my code? Could you show me an example? I'm learning on my own so I'm quite new to this.

Comment: And yes I input a standard .png image

Comment: It was not the complete answer but it put me on the right track, thank you!